# windows service "soft link"

Tags: windows-service, junction-points

I would like to be able to have a nice management tool to allow the rollout of different versions of a windows service over time.

for example I would like to deploy my software (windows service) in version numbered folders, e.g.

c:\wss\v1.0

c:\wss\v1.1

etc

however I dont want to have to reinstall the windows service each time but rather would like to be able to easily point the windows service manager to the new folder.

Are there tools to get this done?

NB: I have used Windows Junctions before (from sysinternals) however I am wondering if there is a nice GUI tool to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Junction Link Magic](http://www.rekenwonder.com/linkmagic.htm) is a (free) GUI utility for managing junction points in Windows.

[Here](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) is another utility I just found through another [ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/134291/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbolic-link-versus-a-junction-when-use-li)...